# Problem sending data with ajax to django server

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to send some ajax data to my  Django server but encounter an error that I have difficulties debugging :
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).
This is my script and part of my django view.

```
function UpdateUserResponse(productId, action, count) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/updateitem/",
    method: "post",
    headers: {  'Content-Type':'application/json', "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
    dataType: "JSON",
     body: JSON.stringify({
      productId : productId,
      action: action,
      count: count
    }),
    success: response => {
      console.log("not relevant to this problem");
    }
  });
}
```

and how i try to receive the data in my view

```
def updateitem(request) :
    data =json.loads(request.body)
    productId=data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    count = data['count']
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I believe instead of the key `body` it should be `data`? i.e. instead of `body: JSON.stringify({...` it should be ``data: JSON.stringify({...``. See the documentation on  [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Yup. That's it... I have some perfectly working ajax with "body" instead of data so I was not looking in the right direction. 
Thanks a lot for your help Abdul Aziz

Answer (score 0):

You ajax request format is invalid. It should be as below.

```
function UpdateUserResponse(productId, action, count) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/updateitem/",
    method: "post",
    headers: {  'Content-Type':'application/json', "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
      'productId' : productId,
      'action': action,
      'count': count
    ),
    success: function(response) {
      console.log('Response', response);
      console.log("not relevant to this problem");
    },
    error : function(xhr, errMsg, err) {
    }
  });
}
```

In your view you would access the request as below.

```
def updateitem(request) :
    if request.method == 'POST':
        productId = request.POST.get('productId')
        action = request.POST.get('action')
        count = request.POST.get('count')
        response_data = {}

        # Your update item to db code goes here 
        # Once update done return response
        response_data['result'] = 'Update item successful!'
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    else:
```

Your console output will be,

```
 Response, {result: "Update item successful!"}
```

Comment: Noted I'll switch methods. What is the problem with the way I was doing it? Performance?
Thanks a lot for taking time to write this answer Zam Abdul

Comment: Now the $.ajax Content-type doesn't match intent

Comment: Both json.loads & request.POST are safe to use. On the other hand, request.post & request.get supports a second parameter which is a default value. Example:- productId 
 = request.POST.get('productId', 100) would use a value 100 if the parameter is not present in the request.